# Is it possible with CSS to target email as a media type?

Tags: css

I have a report generated in html that I would like to prevent certain columns from being included if the report is emailed from the browser. I  imagine something along the lines of mediatype screen, print.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What browser are you using that allows you to email a webpage?

Comment: Internet Explorer, under the page menu in IE10.

Comment: It might be useful for us to know why these columns must be hidden. If they contain sensitive data, you should know that CSS is merely going to hide the data, but it'll still be there if you look in the source.

Answer (score -1):

So if you have a webpage that you want to be altered if it is emailed to someone (i.e., someone clicks a button that says "Share this via E-mail"), then you could add a variable into the url like `http://www.somedomain.com/page_to_be_emailed.html#email` and then use javascript/jQuery to sense the hashtag and remove the necessary elements like so:

```
if(window.location.hash) { 
    var thehash = window.location.hash;
    if (thehash == "#email"){
        //hide some stuff
        $('div.you_want_to_hide').css({'display':'none'});
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have to put this all in a $(document).ready({ }); as well